# iOS FBSDKProfilePictureView returning blank image

Tags: ios, facebook, object, facebook-ios-sdk

So I'm trying to create a simple scrolling bar of pages a user likes, with the image and name displayed. However, the profile view shows a blank image, not a placeholder picture, which means that it's receiving an image to display. After placing some break points in the actual FBSDKProfilePictureView code, specifically at `_updateImageWithData:state:`, it's showing that for each image the data object is only 97 bytes. The funny thing is, when I so something like create a standalone profile picture view, like

```
    FBSDKProfilePictureView *profilePictureView = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(inset, inset, profileSize, profileSize)];
    profilePictureView.profileID = @"4"; //Mark Zuckerberg's id
```

it displays the image properly.

So at first I thought it might have been something to do with setting too many profile ids, thus creating too many url requests, but if I just ran the code below once (i.e. no loop) it still returns the same 97 bytes.

Below is the code I use to generate the scroll view.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numToIterate; i++) {
        NSDictionary *curr = [sharedInterests objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *idNumber = [curr objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *name = [curr objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"getting %@, %@.", name, idNumber);
        // get logo
        FBSDKProfilePictureView *itemView = [[FBSDKProfilePictureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * (smallFrameWidth + horizontalBufferBetweenPics) + horizontalBufferBetweenPics, 0, smallFrameWidth,smallFrameHeight)];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:itemView];
        [itemView setProfileID:idNumber];
        // create description
        UILabel *currDescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * (smallFrameWidth + horizontalBufferBetweenPics) + horizontalBufferBetweenPics, smallFrameHeight, categoryLabelWidth, categoryLabelHeight)];
        currDescriptionLabel.text = name;
        currDescriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
        currDescriptionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12];
        currDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        currDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        [scrollView addSubview:currDescriptionLabel];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [modified version](https://github.com/combinatorial/DBFBProfilePictureView) of FBProfilePictureView that provides error reporting. It allows you to set a completion handler where errors are reported:

```
self.facebookPictureView.completionHandler = ^(DBFBProfilePictureView* view, NSError* error){
    if(error) {
        view.showEmptyImage = YES;
        view.profileID = nil;
        NSLog(@"Loading profile picture failed with error: %@", error);
    } 
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, I still don't know the origin of the error. Did you manually download the images or did you still use the same method as FBProfilePictureView?

Comment: It downloads in the same way, but if you have multiple requests for the same profile id then the image is returned from an in-memory cache. Perhaps that's the difference?

Comment: I don't have any requests for the same id... strange. Also, it seems that the images are lower resolution, do you think this is because you download a lower resolution one or because I'm grabbing multiple images?

Comment: See `- (NSDictionary *)imageQueryParam` for how the size requested is based on the size of the view.

Comment: Sorry for the long turnaround. Turns out you never use the params in refreshImage:, I just added "?fields=url,width,height&height=%d&width=%d" to the end of the url and everything turned out alright. I'm only using square pictures, so this works for me. Some easy changes can be made if you need a non-square image.

Comment: You're right.. not sure how that hasn't been spotted before, thanks!